# Objective C: Trying to create a JSON String with a Dictionary of NSArrays, NSDictionaries and custom objects

Tags: ios, json, nsjsonserialization

I am trying to create a JSON String out of a number of objects.  Basically I am doing this to send up a portion of the database back to the server so it can update what has been done since it was last connected.  I was hoping to be able to convert the dictionary of objects into an NSData or a JSON String and send that up, but I am failing when I attempt to call NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject.  Any thoughts how best to approach this?  Do I need to do each of these objects separately?  Even then, how would I handle the array of custom objects.

```
SchedModel *sched = [self retrieveSchedData]; //custom object
NSArray *event = [self retrieveEvents];  //Array of custom objects
NSDictionary *info = [self retrieveInfo]; //plain old NSDictionary

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

// Load all objects into a dictionary
[dict setObject: sched forKey:@"sched"];
[dict setObject: event forKey:@"event"];
[dict setObject: info forKey:@"info"];

NSError * error = nil;

//Now create the NSData for this object (THIS FAILS)
NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: dict options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
NSString *JSONString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[jsonData bytes] length:[jsonData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't serialize custom objects. You have to convert `sched` to a `NSDictionary` before serialization.

Comment: Is there a generic way to convert sched to a dictionary or would I need to create a toDictionary method in all of my custom objects.

Comment: That'd be the main way, as only you know which properties/iVars should be serialized. However, you can use Obj-C runtime to inspect all properties and encode them.

Comment: You can look at [Mantle](https://github.com/github/Mantle) that does something like that.